# What does (int) mean in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've encountered sometimes code like this and I am kind  of new to programming. I want to find out what's the meaning behind those objects or data type enclosed in parenthesis.

```
(int)
(datagridview)
(form)
```

Comment: If that's the *exact* code you're finding then what you're finding is a syntax error and not valid C# code.  You're *probably* talking about type casting, but we can't be sure without a valid example.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a full example, but the code might be trying to cast an object to a particular type.

Comment: Take a look at '[Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)' Also '[() Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z4503sa.aspx)'

Answer (score 5):

If you see something like this it's called a cast.  It's used to explicitly convert a data type to another data type.

```
double pi = 3.14159;
int my_int = (int)pi;
```

See [this description on casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) for more details.

Comment: To elaborate more, `int` represents an integer, therefore `my_int` in this case will take the floor value of the variable `pi` thus `my_int` will equal 3. In other words, it will truncate the decimal part. So, casting from a type to another may result in some data loss thus be careful when using it.